# Delete first occuring zeros from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to delete list of zeros occurring initially from the list, but it behaves oddly by the method i tried.

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,0,6,0,14,16,18,0]

for i in a:
    if i == 0: a.remove(i)
    else: pass

print (a)

>>> [0, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 14, 16, 18, 0]
```

but I need an OUTPUT like this

> **[3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 14, 16, 18, 0]**

And also lets assume the list grows or reduces so I cant keep the range of zeros and delete them. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Don't modify lists while you're iterating over them or you'll get unexpected results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your loop skips items. You remove one, then you iterate to the next position.

Just find the position of the first non-zero and trim the list

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,0,6,0,14,16,18,0]

i = 0
while a[i] == 0:
  i+=1

print(a[i:])  # [3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 14, 16, 18, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def removeLeadingZeros(a):
    for l in a:
        if l == 0:
            a = a[1:]
        else:
            break
    return a
```

or if you want it as a oneliner using numpy arrays:

```
a = list(a[np.where(np.array(a) != 0)[0][0]:]) # you could remove the list() if you don't mind using numpy arrays
```

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) drops elements of the iterable as long as the predicate is true:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

a = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x==0, a))
```

Answer (score 2):

slightly different then answers already given, so here goes:

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,0,6,0,14,16,18,0]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i] != 0:
        a = a[i:]
        break

print (a)
```