# How to arrange print statements in graph, python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to arrange slashes in print statement to [Graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2yqm.png)

Below is skeleton of my code

```
y = input("Enter numbers (seperated by space): ")
y_arr = []
y_list = y.split()

for n in range(len(y_list)):
    y_arr.append(int(y_list[n]))

space_no = 0

for x in range(len(y_arr)):
    value = y_arr[x]

    for z in range(value):
        if (x%2 == 0):
            print (" "*space_no,"\\")
            space_no += 1
        else:
            print (" "*space_no,"/")
            space_no += 1
```

`Input` statement take numbers and put it into list, then the slashes are generated based on the value of list item. For exa: if value is 2 then 2 slashes will be printed. Even index values go up, odd index values go down. Print statement is printing every character in new line but I want to arrange them like shown in graph.
How to achieve this?

**code edited to Python 3**

Comment: Are you using `python 2`?

Comment: yes @nobleknight

Comment: Is it necessary or you can shift to `python 3`?

Comment: yes ofcourse I can shift to python 3 that will be okay @nobleknight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like homework, but here it is.

```
y_list = '0 3 1 2 3 6 2 3 6 2 3'.split()

y_arr = []
for n in range(len(y_list)):
    y_arr.append(int(y_list[n]))
    
def cumulative(lists):
    cu_list = []
    length = len(lists)
    cu_list = [sum(lists[0:x:1]) for x in range(0, length+1)]
    return cu_list[1:]
    
space_up = 0
space_dn = 0
last_idx = -1

lines = ['']*max(cumulative([-x if i%2 == 0 else x for i,x in enumerate(y_arr)]))
for x in range(len(y_arr)):
    value = y_arr[x]

    for z in range(value):
        if (x%2 == 0):
            lines[last_idx] += (" "*space_dn+"\\")
            space_dn = len(lines[last_idx])-len(lines[last_idx-1])
            last_idx -= 1
            space_up = 0
        else:
            last_idx += 1
            lines[last_idx] += (" "*space_up+"/")
            try:
                space_up = len(lines[last_idx])-len(lines[last_idx+1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
            space_dn = 0
            
print('\n'.join(lines[::-1]))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not gonna comment on the code. Just place a comment if you have questions.

Comment: Hey @CarlosGaldino very thank you for helping me.
Can you please write in words what cumulative function and this line is doing
`lines = ['']*max(cumulative([-x if i%2 == 0 else x for i,x in enumerate(y_arr)]))`

Comment: Sure. This line is preallocating the array `lines`.  It predicts how many lines the output will need based on the number of 'ups' and 'downs'. Note that, 'cumulative()' is just a function that returns the cumulative sum of a list (read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-cumulative-sum-of-a-list/)). This way, the max of the cumulative sum array indicates the 'peak' of the graph, e.g., if the peak is higher, we will need more lines to plot the graph. Note also that, `[-x if i%2 == 0 else x for i,x in enumerate(y_arr)]` adds a minus sign on even positions.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I understood most of the things by destructuring your code. But I encountered a bug in this, if the first 2 values are 0 then it gives index error

Comment: I think the best way to circumvent that would be to validate the array before running the main loop. You could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357412/delete-first-occuring-zeros-from-a-list-in-python) to remove the zeros from `y_arr` if there is more than two zeros at the beginning. If you have trouble with that I can edit the answer

Comment: No Carlos, I got it. Thanks again, you have been very helpful, I regret I can not upvote your answer due to low reputation but u deserve it.

Comment: Hi Carlos-galdino, I am trying to rewrite your code my way and I have gotten bit confused in this. What is this doing? `lines[last_idx] += (" "*space_dn+"\\")
            space_dn = len(lines[last_idx])-len(lines[last_idx-1])
            last_idx -= 1
            space_up = 0` Please write it in words.

Comment: Well, if the position is even, the "graph" is going down. Then `space_dn` counts the number of spaces necessary to align the "negative slash" when one moves from one line to the line below. Note that, `last_index` is the index of the line we are acting upon. Finally, `space_up` is set to zero because there should be no spaces on `\/`, when the graph is changing direction from "down" to "up".

Comment: I need to understand the printing flow.. is it writing line by line (by predicting the slashes at certain position) or it prints first list value's slashes then goes to first line back and print negative slashes of second value?

Comment: I mean its printing row by row, or in columns?

Comment: Neither. Note that, each item on `lines` is a line. The first one is the bottom one. In the end you just print lines from top to bottom `lines[::-1]`. The flow is such that, at the begging, the script "knows" how many lines is going to be necessary. The first iteration of the `for` loop starts at the bottom line (`last_idx = 0`). After that, each iteration jumps back and forth between the lines (`last_idx` can go up or down) adding spaces and slashes accordingly.